# Dividir sub dicionários em python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Bom galera, eu criei um dict, e o dividi utilizando a função:

```
listOfDicts = [{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k%10==i} for i in range(10)]
```

A partir disso, obtive 10 sublistas:

```
listOfDicts[0 a 9]
listOfDict[0]: {0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10, 30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25, 60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40, 90: 45}
```

Mas e se eu quiser dividir as sublista em tamanhos iguais (no caso tamanho =3) e adicionar em único dict:

```
listOfDict[0]: {{0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10}, {30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25}, {60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40}, {90: 45}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode converter seu dicionário para uma *lista de tuplas* para possibilitar a segmentação em blocos usando o operador de *slicing* nessa lista, veja só:

```
def subdicts(dic, tam):
    tups = list(dic.items())
    return [dict(tups[i: i + tam]) for i in range(0, len(tups), tam)]

dic = { 0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10, 30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25, 60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40, 90: 45 }
sub = subdicts(dic, 3)
print(sub)
```

Saída:

```
[{0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10}, {30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25}, {60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40}, {90: 45}]
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SlimLuckyTransversal)

Comment: Lacobus, muito obrigado! Era quase isso o objetivo, mas faltou um detalhe. Na realidade eu preciso fazer esse processo em 10 sub-dicionários, e armazenar os resultados em uma estrutura de dados, seria possível?